# tarball to another drive

Tags: tar

I'm just creating a tarball of a corrupted USB NTFS Windows drive which I mounted in `/media`. Instead of creating the tarball in on the drive itself `/dev/sdb2` I wish to have it created on my own drive `/dev/sda`. What's the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to put the tarball on the other drive:

```
tar cvf /<mount_point_of_dev_sda>/<archive_name>.tar /media
```

If you want to gzip your tar file add 'z' to tar options (tar czvf) and append.gz at the end of the .tar file.

Comment: maybe `/media/<USB_drive_mount_name>` is more appropriate

Comment: From the user question I assumed that /dev/sdb2 was mounted under /media